# Invoking PropertyChanged from a Method to update properties

Tags: c#, viewmodel, mvp, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to figure out how to update my bool properties inside a `ViewModel` using 
`INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Basically in my ViewModel I pass in a List of string. Each boolean properties check the list to see if a 
string value exists.

Now in my software lifecycle the list will get updated and inturn I would like to update each properties 
using INotifyPropertyChanged.

My question is how do I invoke the INotifyPropertyChanged from a `AddToList` method? Is using a method for this the 
correct direction?

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{   
    private List<string> _listOfStrings;

    public ViewModel(List<string> ListOfStrings)
    {   
        _listOfStrings = ListOfStrings;     
    }

    public bool EnableProperty1 => _listOfStrings.Any(x => x == "Test1");
    public bool EnableProperty2 => _listOfStrings.Any(x => x == "Test2");
    public bool EnableProperty3 => _listOfStrings.Any(x => x == "Test3");
    public bool EnableProperty4 => _listOfStrings.Any(x => x == "Test4");

    public void AddToList(string value)
    {
        _listOfStrings.Add(financialProductType);
        // Should I call the OnPropertyChanged here     
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here would be to manually call `OnPropertyChanged` in the `AddString` method.

```
public void AddToList(string value)
{
    _listOfStrings.Add(financialProductType);
    OnPropertyChanged("EnableProperty1");
    OnPropertyChanged("EnableProperty2");
    // etc
}
```

This is fine if you're not likely to change the class much. If you add another property that's calculated from `_listOfStrings` you'll need to add a `OnPropertyChanged` call here.

Using an `ObservableCollection` doesn't really help because you already know when the list changes (`AddToList`) and you'll still have to trigger all the `OnPropertyChanged` methods anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Would it not be advisable to define a `list` property and have the `OnPropertyChanged` in the setter of the list property which will update the properties? Or will I still need to update the properties?

Comment: @KJSR They're still calculated values from the list, so they'd need their own updates too.

Comment: Ok thank you. It's just that I may have to add more properties and don't like the fact I will need to do OnPropertyChanged("propertyName") everytime :(

Comment: Going with this as will need to invoke OnPropertyChanged for each properties.

Comment: Yeah this is one of those keep it simple, until it becomes a maintenance problem, then make it more complex, situations.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there are 2 things you are missing in your implementation:

1. You should use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`. As the name suggest, the former one can be `observed` (notify about its changing) by the view.
2. You need to bind a control to the public ObservableCollection and call OnPropertyChanged every time you assign/change value of the collection. something like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _myList;
// your control should bind to this property
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
{
    get => return _myList;
    set
    {
        // assign a new value to the list
        _myList = value;
        // notify view about the change
        OnPropertiyChanged(nameof(MyList));
    }
}


// some logic in your view model
string newValue = "newValue";
_myList.Add(newValue );
OnPropertyCHanged(nameof(MyList));
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am assuming I will still need to update the individual properties?

Comment: Of course, my friend. Whenever you change the property, just call "OnPropertyChanged" to notify the bound control in view about the change of your property.